# Selenium WebDriver Disabled my Firefox addons

Tags: c#, winforms, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium WebDriver in my C# winforms application. When I run application and open Firefox, my addons are disabled. How to leave the addons enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the desired addons to ON. For example, if you want to enable firebug, find out the location of the zip or xpi of the addon and then use the following code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffprofile.AddExtension("C:\\firebug.xpi");
ffprofile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.11.4");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I did to resolve is just by adding following to the `pom.xml` and it worked fine for me. Currently I'm running tests on Firefox 43.0.3 with Selenium 2.48.2. and also by have a dependency for the Firefox browser in the `pom.xml`.

> org.seleniumhq.selenium selenium-firefox-driver 2.48.2
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium selenium-java 2.48.2

After using this if you fail to use your add on  than  drop message I will provide you some more options but hope fully  you will get result from this.